# How to get PCIe SSD in RAD0 mode work in Linux?

Tags: linux, dual-boot, ssd

I have a Dell XPS 13 laptop. It has a PCIe SSD installed. It is configured to work in RAID0 mode, and can be changed to AHCI.

But changing this setting will cause to reinstall my Windows system, which I'd rather not.

Is there any way to get the SSD to be recognized in Linux without changing to AHCI mode?

Comment: How is the RAID performed? If it is in pure hardware you should see a single disk instead of all the RAID disks (the disk controller should take care of RAID and appear to be almost AHCI).  If the RAID is performed by the other OS (i.e. at software level) you shall absolutely never try to write to the disk from a different OS.

Comment: It is a BIOS configuration, I guess it is a RAID by hardware. But I do not see any RAID devices in `/dev/`. I do not know if it performs better than AHCI. It is the default setting, and I prefer not to change it as Windows will not like the change.